# Java Paths.get() strange behavior on Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, path, java-7

I am currently writing some code in which I work with files a lot. I implemented all file paths processing (concatenation, normalization, etc) using the Java 7 nio classes Paths and Path. On Windows everything works as expected however on Linux the Paths class behavior seems to be broken.

For example the following code:

```
    System.out.println(File.separator);
    System.out.println(FileSystems.getDefault());
    Path path = Paths.get("../dir1/", "\\dir2\\file1").toAbsolutePath().normalize();
    System.out.println(path);
    if(path.toFile().exists()) {
        System.out.println(path + " exists");
    }
```

on Windows prints the following output:

```
\
sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem
D:\projects\dir1\dir2\file1
true
```

but the same code on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 on both Java 1.7.0_79 (64 bit) and Java 1.8.0_60 (64 bit) leaves the path un-normalized:

```
/
sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem
/home/semi/dir1/\dir2\file1
```

Also even if the file is at path `/home/semi/dir1/dir2/file1` exists it is reported as non-existent by `path.toFile().exists()`.

I looked a bit over [LinuxFileSystem.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/nio/fs/LinuxFileSystem.java) and [WindowsFileSystem.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystem.java) and it seems that on windows the path is checked for both `/` and `\` characters (in `WindowsPathParser.isSlash(char c)` method). Shouldn't the Linux implementation do the same?

Is this a bug in `sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystem` implementation or am I doing something wrong?

Also do you know any alternative to make sure Linux paths are parsed and normalized correctly (without doing all the parsing manually).

Comment: It’s the other way round: the fact that the `WindowsFileSystem` silently treats `/` as a separator despite such a behavior is nowhere specified can be considered a bug. Or a convenience feature, whichever way of looking at it you prefer. Unfortunately, such behavior leads to developers expecting magic from implementations…

Comment: If you would construct the the `Path` on path elements `Path path = Paths.get("..", "dir1", "dir2", "file1").toAbsolutePath().normalize();` you could avoid such problems and you do not need to handle yourself the `File.separator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, `/` is not a valid character in a filename so any code can assume it's a wrongly typed path separator.

In Linux, just about any byte is acceptable in a filename. In your `Paths.get()`, you're effectively joining a path called `dir1` (1 level deep) and a path called `\dir2\file1` (also 1 level deep).

Comment: So, in short, use `/` as a path separator, basically all the time unless dealing with something really esoteric.

Comment: If you have to use strings, using `/` is a good idea, but I would use native path concatenation tools (like `Paths.get()`) or manually with `File.separator` in your code, like you have done already.

Comment: It did not cross my mind that '\' might be an accepted Linux filename character. Now it makes sense, I will continue to use Paths.get and make sure no '\' are used in my paths. Thank you :)

Comment: good info: backslash is the source of many avoidable problems.

Answer (score 1):

Java on Windows is compiled against Microsoft C++ standard libraries, which permit either backslash or forward slash as a valid path separator.  So backslash is a valid path separator only when running on Windows, whereas forward slash is valid everywhere.

The only time backslash is required, even on Windows, is when creating command lines that will be passed to CMD.EXE, to PowerShell, and possibly other terminals/shells.  There are also some open source libraries that require backslash in file paths (when running on Windows), but java itself permits either forward or back slash in file paths.

IMHO, using File.separator when parsing input often leads to avoidable errors, whereas it has a valid role when generating output to be consumed by software or human eyeballs.